# Error in warranty date - strtotime

Tags: php

I'm going to create warranty date using warranty day, month and years. This function is working properly when enter one record at a time. but I have to enter several warranty days for different items in same form.

```
for($value = 0; $value < count(array_filter($part_name1)); $value++){               
    if(!empty($year1[$value])||!empty($month1[$value])||!empty($days1[$value])){
        $warranty_date   = $this->purchase_date;
        if(!empty($days1[$value])){
            $warranty = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
            $warranty = strtotime("+".$this->days." day", $warranty);
            $warranty = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
            $warranty_date = $warranty;
        }

        if(!empty($month1[$value])){
            $warranty        = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
            $warranty        = strtotime("+".$this->month." month", $warranty);
            $warranty        = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
            $warranty_date   = $warranty;
        }

        if(!empty($this->year)){
            $warranty        = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
            $warranty        = strtotime("+".$this->year." year", $warranty);
            $warranty        = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
            $warranty_date   = $warranty;
        }


    }
}
```

Please help me to find error of this code.

this function base on the purchase date.
When I enter several record then 1st warrant date show like `1970-01-01` and Second record warranty date correct and rest of others show `1970-01-01`.

Comment: it show 1st record 1970-01-01, 2nd record correct date, and 3rd 4th etc.. show 1970-01-01

Comment: Is your array correct?

Comment: @BartFriederichs - yes, I print it several time. It was working fine.

Comment: Could you post the data inside that array?

Answer (score 2):

```
you missed last curly brace 

<?php 


for($value = 0; $value < count(array_filter($part_name1)); $value++){               
            if(!empty($year1[$value])||!empty($month1[$value])||!empty($days1[$value])){
                $warranty_date   = $this->purchase_date;
                if(!empty($days1[$value])){
                    $warranty = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
                    $warranty = strtotime("+".$this->days." day", $warranty);
                    $warranty = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
                    $warranty_date = $warranty;
                }

                if(!empty($month1[$value])){
                    $warranty        = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
                    $warranty        = strtotime("+".$this->month." month", $warranty);
                    $warranty        = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
                    $warranty_date   = $warranty;
                }

                if(!empty($this->year)){
                    $warranty        = strtotime($this->warranty_date);
                    $warranty        = strtotime("+".$this->year." year", $warranty);
                    $warranty        = date('Y-m-d', $warranty);
                    $warranty_date   = $warranty;
                }


            }
}  // this one

 ?>
```

Comment: This isn't the problem; they just forgot the bracket in their question.. which they have since rectified.